# Converting Excel formula to SQL Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Good morning Stack, I am in need of some major help.

I have to convert an EXCEL Formula to a SQL case.
The whole thing keeps falling apart on me when I get to the last section. I can't for the life of me figure out how to set this up properly, and I am tired of getting kicked in the nads over it.

My main problem is how excel handles Multiple "Else" potions of its If/then's

Here is the Excel :

```
=IF(AND(W7+H7<=0,IF(E7-H7-S7>0,E7-H7-S7,0)<=0),0,IF(W7+H7<IF(E7-H7-S7>0,E7-H7-S7,0),IF(W7+H7<0,0,W7+H7),IF(E7-H7-S7>0,IF(W7>H7,E7-S7,H7+AF7),H7)))
```

Here is the relevant sections and how they have been converted to SQL so far.

```
E4 = TotInChar.TotInChar
H4 = CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2))
W4 = CAST(tmpdc.[14]AS decimal(10,2))
S4 = T4MathBlock.TTIV
AF4 = [AmountIncluded].[Amount]
```

Here is the SQL Case I have done so far:
(Its designed to be part of an Outer Apply, as I am handling all math portions in their own Outer apply. That way anyone that comes behind me will find the code segmented and documented properly)

```
SELECT (CASE 
    WHEN CAST(tmpdc1.[14]AS decimal(10,2))+(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2))) <= 0
                AND (CASE WHEN(TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV) >0 
                        THEN TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV
            ELSE '0.00' END) <=0 THEN '0.00'
    /* part 2*/     
    WHEN CAST(tmpdc1.[14] AS decimal(10,2))+(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))
                < 
            (CASE WHEN (TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV)
                 > 0 
            THEN TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV
                ELSE '0.00' 
            END)
            THEN (TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV)
    /*Part 3*/

    WHEN CAST(tmpdc.[14]AS decimal(10,2))+CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)) 
            < 0 THEN '0.00' 
        ELSE (CAST(tmpdc.[14]AS decimal(10,2))+CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))
    /*Part 4*/                                      

    WHEN TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV
             > 0  THEN
                 (CASE(CAST(tmpdc.[14]AS decimal(10,2)) > CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2))
                    THEN TotInChar.TotInChar - T4MathBlock.TTIV ELSE '0.00')
        ELSE CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))
    End 



End) AS[ANT4]
 From #TempDisclosure tmpdc1 
                     WHERE tmpdc1.[Number] = Tmpdc.[Number]
```

Thank you for any help you can give on this, I have been working at it for about 10 hours now, and my brain just hurts

Comment: I suggest starting again.  Do one step at a time, and once you have an individual part working, leave it alone.

Comment: Yea, I have done this, a few times now, the above is my 4th attempt at the whole thing. At this point I need another set of eyes on it, as I am getting wall eyed. 
We've all been here before, where you need to just walk away and get someone else to say "Hey man, you forgot a ")" or something similar.

Comment: 'Multiple "Else" potions', eh?

Comment: I suggest translating the Excel formula into English / pseudo code before attempting to generate the corresponding SQL.

Comment: Yea, I have, I didn't provide that though, I didn't want to post a larger wall of text than I already did. I will edit it in now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick paren match shows there may be an error in the last section...

you have this:

```
WHEN TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV
         > 0  THEN
             (CASE(CAST(tmpdc.[14]AS decimal(10,2)) > CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2))
                THEN TotInChar.TotInChar - T4MathBlock.TTIV ELSE '0.00')
    ELSE CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))
End
```

Try this:

```
WHEN TotInChar.TotInChar -(CAST(tmpdc1.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc1.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))- T4MathBlock.TTIV
         > 0  THEN
             (CASE(CAST(tmpdc.[14]AS decimal(10,2)) > CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))
                THEN TotInChar.TotInChar - T4MathBlock.TTIV ELSE '0.00'
    ELSE CAST(tmpdc.[3]AS Decimal (10,2)) + CAST(tmpdc.[5]AS Decimal (10,2)))
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it.
Formulate the CASE assuming that all are integers. The details of casting should come later.
At present the solution you have is so cluttered that its impossible to verify if it matches the Excel formula or not.

Comment: I started again to do each section as an outer apply, to then pull into the select the values for comparing.

But in doing that I hit another error, so I am backing off again, to try moving from using the outer apply's, to doing the comparison in the upper "main" select

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code that I used to break it down.

```
DECLARE a int;
DECLARE b int;

SET a = (W7 + H7);
SET b = (E7 - H7 - S7);

IF (b < 0) THEN b = 0;

IF (a <= 0 AND b <= 0) THEN BEGIN
    0
END ELSE BEGIN
    IF (a < b) THEN BEGIN
        IF (a < 0) THEN BEGIN
            0
        END ELSE BEGIN
            a
        END
    END ELSE BEGIN
        IF (b > 0) THEN BEGIN
            IF (W7 > H7) THEN BEGIN
                E7 - S7
            END ELSE BEGIN
                H7 + AF7
            END
        END ELSE BEGIN
            H7
        END
    END
END
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, I can't put a Declare/ Set in an outer apply. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user1949329 correct, I just got part of the way of working through your problem and had to do somthing else. Rather than abandon what I had I thought I may as well post it.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate the response, I am trying to work with it now.

I am taking your post and converting it to a series of outer applies. I can then do the case with the inherent references. Should make it easier. I will post later if this works out. Thank you

Comment: @user1949329 you can see that most the complexity is actually a fallback to 0.

Comment: Yea, and actually your post makes me rethink the entire 400+ lines I have written so far.

I am walking away now, but I will be redoing the entire set of code come Monday. I think it will work out better for me in the long run. Using your example as a guide, I will be changing how all of the math is done in the piece, and then just referencing those "set" equations as needed.

Comment: @user1949329 in the end you'll have something more maintainable and it should help you with performance, if thats a concern.